What conditions create subharmonic oscillations in switching converters?
I have been thinking that any time you're in CCM with a duty cycle greater than 50%, you can enter subharmonic oscillations. Is this only for current mode control, or is it voltage mode as well?

This is one of those cases where my mind switches to German and thinks, "Verstehen Sie, was Sie sagen, oder wiederholen Sie einfach, was Sie woanders gehört haben?" Or, "You may think so because you read that it is so. But that's different than understanding it yourself and under what conditions." A quick search finds this answer that may be worth a second's time.

You can have a look at this paper that I published a while ago. A CCM CM converter features two loops, an inner current loop and an outer voltage loop. The inner loop can be unstable in some conditions. A VM converter features one loop only, except if you have a current limit circuit which can, in fault conditions, also exhibit instabilities.

The 50% threshold is oft-repeated and erroneous to begin with, but you haven't taken note of the specific case under which it arises.
There are two common cases actually, that I'm aware of:

For average current mode control, I don't know the analysis, but the general idea is that too much ripple into the error amplifier, or (to a similar end) current error amp pole too close to Fsw, can cause a single bifurcation.
For peak current mode control, operation in CCM without slope compensation causes bifurcation.

Bifurcation is a term from chaos theory.  In an iterated system, if, as a control parameter varies, the number of steady-state values iterated through goes from a single stable point to two (alternating) points, or two to four, etc., that point is called a bifurcation point.
Peak current mode control is in fact an analog implementation of the logistic map -- a much easier implementation than a naive one using multipliers and sample-and-hold functions to implement the mathematical function as given -- and the parameter is ripple fraction.  The iterated value can be expressed as duty for a given cycle, or average current during the cycle.  As current goes continuous, some current remains at the start of the next cycle: a free variable to which the control is blind. It happens that this variable is unstable, and quickly diverges, to the point where one cycle is DCM (the initial current is so high, the pulse is short, leaving plenty of time for the inductor to discharge), and the other is CCM.  The DCM is the "blowoff valve" terminating the chaotic cycle to length N = 2.  If deeper CCM is pushed, it rises to a cycle of 4, with the last pulse in the cycle having the lowest duty and dropping into DCM just briefly.
And so on.  You can guess that, as CCM gets deeper, the span between period doubling must get shorter (or, the doubling gets exponentially (hyperbolically?) more frequent), because, at a higher setpoint, there is less and less chance for some sequence of pulses to still manage to dip into DCM.
Subharmonic oscillation (or out-and-out chaos: a typical symptom of such a converter in deep CCM is a hissing sound) is undesirable because it increases peak and RMS currents (that is, peak is reached more often than it has to), and input current and output voltage ripple are both increased, and pushed to lower frequencies where filtering it is harder.  Acoustic noise is also increased.
The reason 50% is oft-quoted, is because the simplest analysis case is a 1:1 flyback, or 1:2 boost or 2:1 buck, and CCM simply happens at 50% when voltages are as given.  And with ideal switches and all.
I don't happen to know the path of citations that led to this dilution of knowledge; probably a book some decades ago wrote the 50% threshold, in context of these settings, and meant the point to be synonymous with CCM, and used both synonymously in prose as such.  Then someone quoted just a fraction of that, discarding context of that synonymy, and the rest is history -- the meme spreads, on its own merits and for its own sake, divorced from the original state of knowledge that it was created under.  Never underestimate the ability for application notes to repeat questionable or out-and-out wrong information!
Even books often repeat this factoid, sadly.  In the end, there is no substitute for critical thought, independent verification, and proof.
If slope compensation is included, we sum the oscillator ramp with the switch current slope, and we get a hybrid case between a pure voltage-mode converter (PWM depends on voltage error amp output alone), and peak current mode control.  This makes the converter less sensitive to inductor current, forcing more robust components (higher worst-case current must be endured), and impairing what current regulation it had (input/output current limits vary with voltage ratio).  The stability range is extended about in relation to the fraction of slope compensation used: more than 2 or 3x compensation stretches the design a bit too far, limiting the practical ripple fraction to 30-40%, which you see often in practical designs -- this at least is enough to reduce core and capacitor losses, though still usually requiring ferrite core inductors, but not litz wire for example.
To achieve lower ripple fractions, another control scheme is required.  Constant on/off time, hysteretic, and average current mode are all feasible options for lower ripple fractions.  Mind, hysteretic (at least the most basic form e.g. MC34063) has numerous downsides, with high output voltage ripple (and weird subharmonic dependencies with load current) being a particular blemish.

Amending an edit here, as I don't particularly care to revise or incorporate it into the above here, but simply add something concrete for sake of motivation, and showing actual workings-out.
For the circuit,

Consider waveforms like so:

(Excuse the scratchings, I changed my mind about what notation I wanted to use.  A discrete-time formulation seems the most reasonable here, so I will use lowercase to indicate a time-series signal, with index in braces.  Capitals are constants.)
For the ideal boost converter, we have:
$$V_o > V_i \\
I_\text{pk} = \frac{V_c}{R_s} \\
T = \frac{1}{F_\text{sw}} \\
\Delta I_L = \frac{dI_L}{dt} \Delta t
$$
\begin{equation}
\frac{dI_L}{dt} = 
    \begin{cases}
        \frac{V_i}{L} , & \text{switch on} \\
        \frac{V_o - V_i}{L} , & \text{switch off}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
And the duty per cycle \$d[n]\$, and current at start of cycle \$i[n]\$, are as labeled.  (That may be drawn a bit unclear: the second rising edge is \$d[1]T + T\$ and the final falling edge is \$2T\$.)
Suppose we start at initial current \$i[0]\$.  The clock pulses and the switch runs for,
$$ d[0] = \left( I_\text{pk} - i[0] \right) \frac{L}{V_1 T} $$
it is off for another \$(1-d[0])T\$, bringing us to time \$T\$, and the current changes to,
$$ i[1] = I_\text{pk} + \frac{V_i - V_o}{L} (1 - d[0])T $$
Eliminate \$d[0]\$ from these two equations by substitution, and solve for \$i[1]\$.
Now we get a recurrence relation, for the current of the next cycle start, in terms of the proceeding cycle's.
Expanding this a few times gets us, for example,
$$ i[3] = \left( \frac{T \left( V_i - V_o \right)}{L} + \frac{I_\text{pk} V_o}{V_i} \right) \left( 1 + \delta + \delta^2 \right) + i[0] \delta^3$$
I assert (but do not prove leave as an exercise for the student to prove) it follows by induction that,
$$ i[n] = \left( \frac{T \left( V_i - V_o \right)}{L} + \frac{I_\text{pk} V_o}{V_i} \right) \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \delta^i + i[0] \delta^n $$
where \$\delta = 1 - \frac{V_o}{V_i}\$.
This arithmetic is easily solved by anyone who's completed lower calculus units (arguably even highschool calc, if/when offered?), and knows basic circuit analysis and equations (maybe beyond AC Steady State, because the differential form for the inductor equation is used here, not the sinusoidal case).  For the current \$i[n]\$ to exist in general (for long time scales, \$n \rightarrow \infty\$), we need two facts:

The geometric series must exist
The power \$\delta^n\$ must be finite

We have divergence for \$V_o \le V_i\$, or swapped signs, which makes sense: in either case, the inductor never unloads, current diverges no matter how often we switch the poor flip-flop.
We also have divergence for \$V_o \ge 2 V_i\$, where both the geometric series and \$\delta^n\$ have alternating runaway values.  For a lossless CCM boost like this, this is equivalent to the 50% duty case, often quoted.
Note this isn't aware of edge cases like current reversing or the switch time taking multiple cycles; though I don't think that actually makes a difference, and if nothing else, we can set the ripple fraction arbitrarily low (\$L\$ and \$F_\text{sw}\$ arbitrarily high) to, at least make it highly unlikely, if not impossible, for that to happen.  In particular, if a \$d[n]\$ happens to be greater than 1, it simply skips a clock pulse, but the indexing remains intact as long as we are keeping track of real falling edges, not clock pulses.
This does not take into account losses anywhere (which may act to dampen the alternation, but make analysis much more complicated by introducing time constants everywhere), or slope compensation; it also seems to miss the richness of the system, as the above equation is not equivalent to the logistic map, and a different process is necessary to obtain that form.

It is possible to show that the inner current loop introduces a pair of complex RHP zeroes. Sampled data analysis from Ridley in the 90's has demonstrated it. When these RHP zeroes are included within the voltage loop, they turn in a pair of complex LHP poles at $\frac{F_{SW}}{2}$. The denominator of the control-to-output transfer function can be expressed as a low-frequency pole cascaded with a 2nd-order polynomial, with a $Q$. The $Q$ depends on $D$. For $D$ less than 50%, the step response if damped, for $D$=50%, the poles are imaginary and beyond 50%, they jump to the RHP.

Is that based around the same assumptions outlined above, or is it true regardless of operating point?  I've certainly stabilized voltage loops at >50% so it can't be that insurmountable, but I suppose I don't know if that might happen due to other factors like capacitor value and choice (ESR a factor?), or if the analysis only applies to a type 1 control (90° phase shift near Fsw) or what.

I gave an answer on SE about the current loop that becomes instable but there is no peaking effect in the loop itself. Using a digital modulator, it is possible with SIMPLIS, to observe the effect of adding slope compensation: it lowers the current loop gain (as you were increasing the sense resistance) and forces crossover at a region where phase margin is better.

Dr. Vorpérian came out with a simpler analysis of the CM issue in his paper from 1990 and he built a simpler model, not based on sampled data analysis. The interesting this is that he determine a control-to-output transfer function similar to Ridley's. When you stabilize loops with $D$ greater than 50%, you need to inject quite a bit of external ramp and you make the converter operate closer to voltage-mode in which the external ramp amplitude becomes less negligible with respect to $i_L$.

Hmm. I've been looking at the Vorpérian paper from time to time over the last few days. I'm only three pages in, and I could already write significant critique about it. Suffice it to say, I do not find it very readable, or practical, and while I haven't read the whole thing, it seems to me a case of academics writing for an academic audience, or applying excessively heavy-handed solutions to trivial (in comparison) problems. Maybe this surprises you, maybe this says more about me than the paper, I don't know.

In any case, I took a couple hours today to work out the solution for myself. Why this required 13 pages to analyze, or the bulk(?) of Ridley's paper with a different sledge-hammer method, I don't know, but it's pretty basic when one doesn't get stuck in the weeds.

Tim, the IEEE format does not lend itself well to explaining things in details and Vorpérian's paper are sometimes difficult to follow. I would recommend you have a look at my seminar 5 in this list where I detail how the CM PWM switch model is built. It is truly the simplest and most efficient way to model current mode with two controlled sources. Using this approach, I later derived a DCM model and it is extremely useful for stability analysis. Can't be beaten in simplicity.

@VerbalKint -- Does BCM have fewer zeros?

@MicroservicesOnDDD, BCM still has the ESR-related zero plus a high-frequency right-half-plane zero. I derived the transfer function of a BCM current-flyback with multiple valley switching in this document.
